# How to calculate sum of squares of each cell for a row in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, square

i have a dataframe like this

| Index | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

i want to take the square for each cell in a row and add them up then put the result in a column "sum of squares", how to do that ?

i expect this result :

| Index | A | B | C | D | E | sum of squares |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 53 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 25 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `apply()` and `sum()`.

**Code:-**

```
import pandas as pd
lis=[(4,2,4,4,1),
     (1,4,1,4,4),
     (3,1,2,0,1),
     (1,0,2,2,4),
     (0,1,1,0,2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(lis)
df.columns =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E']
#print(df)

# Main code
new=df.apply(lambda num: num**2) #Square of each number stored in new.

#Creating new column sum_of_squares applying sum() function on new
df['sum_of_squares']=new.sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:-**

```
   A  B  C  D  E  sum_of_squares
0  4  2  4  4  1              53
1  1  4  1  4  4              50
2  3  1  2  0  1              15
3  1  0  2  2  4              25
4  0  1  1  0  2               6
```